# FlatList doesn't get rendered in component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've made a FlatList which supposed to render a sample list.

Here's a code what i've done already. As simple as can be.

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>before</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={[1,2,3,4,5]}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log("hello" + item)
                    return (
                        <View><Text>{item}</Text></View>
                    )
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item,index) => String(index)}
            />
            <Text>after</Text>
        </View>
```

And now 'before' get's render, as well as 'after'.
Console.logs also get triggered.

But flat list doesnt...

[image: That's what i got rendered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you background color isn't black. Maybe you don't see it because the text is the same color as the background.

Also, what is inside `styles.container`? Maybe that is the cause of it now showing. 
Please provide what is inside `styles.container` and if you render more things in the component that can make a difference.

Comment: But as i said, i DO render two text "before" and "after"

Comment: @iwannabeprogrammer and what is in `styles.container`?

Comment: "flex" : 1 only

Comment: @iwannabeprogrammer try removing that and see if it show the flatlist